# Setting Library Parameter Globally (Newtonsoft.Json MaxDepth)

Tags: c#, oop, security, .net-core, json.net

I'm trying to upgrade a monolithic repo so that it is no longer susceptible to this [NewtonsSoft.Json Exploit](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5crp-9r3c-p9vr). I'm new to C# so maybe that's why I'm having a little trouble understanding the fix. They say

> This can be done globally with he following statement:
>
> `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings { MaxDepth = 128 };`

I think I could just set this in each classes constructor that relies on Newtonsoft, but that would create a whole lot of duplication (example below). Am I totally off, is there a cleaner way to do things?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json

private class MyClasss
{
    public MyClass()
    {
      // add this line here
      JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings { MaxDepth = 128 };
      // other steps
    }
    // other methods
}
```

Notes:

1. I'm working in a monolithic repo full of a bunch of solutions that each contain multiple projects.
2. We can't update to Json.NET 13.0.1 because of some external dependencies.
3. We are using .Net 3.1 and there seems to be about 5 entrypoints to our repo.

Comment: `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` is a `public static Func<JsonSerializerSettings>` so why not just set it globally on startup?  Or is your "monolithic repo" a library with no single entry point?  Also Json.NET [13.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/13.0.1) has been modified so that *JsonReader and JsonSerializer MaxDepth defaults to 64*, so could you just update to 13.0.1?

Comment: Also, what version of .NET are you using?  .NET 5 or something earlier?

Comment: The default value is 64; is this not sufficient for you? Do you need further depth? If not: you don't need anything other than an update, is my understanding

Comment: I'm using .Net 6 and there seems to be about 5 entrypoints.  Also, we can't update to 13.0.1 because of some external dependencies. So just to clarify I would just run that code in say each relevant "Program.cs"?

Comment: Sorry I just checked and I'm using .Net 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/p_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert_defaultsettings.htm) is a [`public static Func<JsonSerializerSettings>`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/d0a328e8a46304d62d2174b8bba54721d02be3d3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs#L62), so you only really need to set it once, on startup.

You have a few options for doing this which should be easier than setting it in every class constructor:

1. You note that your monolithic repo has 5 entry points, so you could set `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` in each `Program.cs`.
2. If you have some class that is used by all consumers of your monolithic repo, you could set `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` in the static constructor for that class:

   ```cs
   public class SomeUniversallyUsedClass
   {
       static SomeUniversallyUsedClass()
       {
           // add this line here
           JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings { MaxDepth = 128 };
       }

       // Remainder of the class
   }
   ```
3. You mention you are using <del>.NET 6</del> .NET Core 3.1.  In c# 9.0/.NET 5 and later, you can use a [module initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/general#moduleinitializer-attribute) to set `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` once for every module in your monolithic repo like so:

   ```cs
   internal class JsonNetModuleInitializer
   {
       [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ModuleInitializer]
       public static void Initialize()
       {
         // add this line here
         JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings { MaxDepth = 128 };
       }
   }
   ```

   If you are using a version earlier than .NET 5, you could still introduce `JsonNetModuleInitializer` and call `JsonNetModuleInitializer.Initialize()` from your 5 entry points and/or the static constructors for your commonly used classes.

   Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xRhXXl).

Comment: This is great, I actually messed up and we are using .net 3.1 :( sorry about that. But I think a combination of 1 and 2 should work for me. Do you know if there's a cleaner way to include the the JsonConver setting in all the static constructors (i.e. without duplicating)?

Comment: Well you can always just add some other static class `JsonNetModuleInitializer` with a `public static void Initialize()` method and call it where needed.